# No POST request made when logging into website - cannot automate logging in to Crunchbase

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, post, python-requests

I'm trying to use cloudscraper (a Python package that bypasses Cloudfare blockers for certain websites) to automate logging in to Crunchbase (and ultimately scraping information off their platform, without an API, since this is only available to enterprise users).

```
payload = {
    "email": "...",
    "pass": "..."
}

with scraper as session:
    session.post("https://www.crunchbase.com/login", data=payload)
```

I'm trying to figure out parameter values for my payload variable to post to the login page, but I'm not sure what these are and the 'Network' tab on Chrome is not showing any 'login' element as being posted (POST) to the Crunchbase site after I login - please see screenshot.

[image]

Some help as to what the correct parameter values for the payload could be would be much appreciated - thank you :)

Comment: Why not just use selenium?

Comment: @D4NieLDev Crunchbase has an automation sensor which knocks back Selenium :(